# Does ROS2 require Python3?

Tags: ros, ros2, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the ROS2 beta install I saw it required pip3.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265849/does-ros2-require-python3?/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2017-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is documented in the [ROS2 Developers Guide](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Developer-Guide), specifically the [Language Versions and Code Format - Python](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Developer-Guide#python) section:

> We will target Python 3 for our development.

and also the *Changes between ROS 1 and ROS 2* article on `design.ros2.org`, section [Platforms and dependencies - Languages - Python](http://design.ros2.org/articles/changes.html#c-standard), which is more specific:

> ROS 1 is targeting Python 2. ROS 2 requires at least Python version 3.5.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4